# Как называются окна размер которых можно менять мышкой?

Tags: css, bootstrap, angularjs, веб-дизайн

Представьте что экран разделен на две равные части образовывая два окна с видимой разграничительной рамкой. И вот мышкой берешь и двигаешь эти рамки делая тем самым одно окно больше или меньше другого. Как это правильно называется чтобы найти похожее в css + js?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это называется сплиттер (splitter). Как пример [Двойная панель (splitter)](http://novice2ninja.ru/ninja-book/chapter-3/splitter.html)

Answer (score 3):

Обычно это просто два div'a, в упрощенном виде с навешанными событиями мыши, исходя из перемещения мыши, меняется размер блока. Есть много плагинов, например: https://jqueryui.com/resizable/ , гуглить можно по ключевым словам: draggable resize container.

Answer (score 2):

Возможно это формы с динамической структурой.

Comment: У меня не получилось что-то в гугле найти.

Answer (score 2):

может быть это фреймы. как в игре combats? резиновые div

Answer (score 2):

CSS3 resize property -

```
div {
    border: 2px solid;
    padding: 20px; 
    width: 300px;
    resize: horizontal;
    overflow: auto;
}
```